# Chart.js : Controller for Scatter chart doesn't work for draw function

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Following this [link](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html) to extend Scatter type with draw() function to print "No Data Found" in the center but with the Y axis scale.

Here's the code:

```
Chart.defaults.derivedScatter = Chart.defaults.scatter;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var custom = Chart.controllers.scatter.extend({
    draw: function() {
        Chart.controllers.scatter.prototype.draw.call(this);

        this.chart.chart.ctx.textAlign = "center";
        this.chart.chart.ctx.font = "11px Arial";
        this.chart.chart.ctx.fillText("No data found", 45, 100);
    }
});

Chart.controllers.derivedScatter = custom;

chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "derivedScatter",
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    max:0.10,
                    stepSize:0.001,
                    callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                        var n = parseFloat(label);
                        return (Math.round(n*1000)/10).toFixed(1);
                    }
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
                gridLines: {
                   display: false
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            display:false
        },
        responsive: false
    }
});
```

I am getting the Y axis scale but I don't see No data found as a text in the center of the chart. It doesn't seem to work.

Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966817/how-to-add-text-inside-the-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604116/chart-js-how-to-add-text-in-the-middle-of-the-chart) stack-overflow answers to come up with this solution.

Note: [Here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types) it doesn't say they have a built in type for Scatter. Is that the reason?

Any other approach or any other help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it­*'s* not working is because, you haven't initialized the `data` property of your chart. In order to use your extended dataset controller, you must initialize / set the `data.datasets` property while constructing your chart, like so :

```
...
chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: "derivedScatter",
   data: {
      datasets: [{}]
   },
   options: {
...
```

***note:***  the important part is to initialize the `datasets` property and it doesn't necessarily have to contain any data.

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

Chart.defaults.derivedScatter = Chart.defaults.scatter;

var custom = Chart.controllers.scatter.extend({
   draw: function() {
      Chart.controllers.scatter.prototype.draw.call(this);

      this.chart.chart.ctx.textAlign = "center";
      this.chart.chart.ctx.font = "11px Arial";
      this.chart.chart.ctx.fillText("No data found", 80, 80);
   }
});

Chart.controllers.derivedScatter = custom;

chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: "derivedScatter",
   data: {
      datasets: [{}]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               max: 0.10,
               stepSize: 0.001,
               callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                  var n = parseFloat(label);
                  return (Math.round(n * 1000) / 10).toFixed(1);
               }
            },
            gridLines: {
               display: false,
               drawBorder: false
            }
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            display: false,
            gridLines: {
               display: false
            }
         }]
      },
      legend: {
         display: false
      },
      responsive: false
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```